# Files are missing or deleting after resource is out of sync error in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

Please help! Today i was working on a android project and suddenly i got a message 
***.xml files are out of sync Please refresh**. After refreshing i found that there is no res,src and layout directory under project directory. Even files are not present in physical directory, i am very confused and in trouble Please help! how to recover missing files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you delete any folder or file?

Comment: no i was just trying to add image file !

Comment: Did you close eclipse after that? If not, don't close

Comment: yes i restarted the eclipse

Comment: Right click your layout folder and click on the option `Restore from local history'

Comment: Accept my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your layout folder and click on the option `Restore from local history`